# Synchronize two Oracle databases

Tags: oracle, synchronization

I have two oracle databases. Database A and Database B. Database B should be in sync with Database A. Data within DB- B wont be altered, it is only for view purpose. All the data change in DB- A should reflect in DB- B. After googling, I found db link and Materialized view 
could help but I am not clear how to use them. Please give any idea.

Comment: You should be reading about Oracle replication instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read the following:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14191/rcmdupdb.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL100

A [materialized view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm) can be used for replication purposes but what you are referring to is *[duplication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14191/rcmdupdb.htm)* not *[replication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28324/tdpii_reppit.htm#BEHHGGIB)*.

If you all have a DBA in your org most definitely hand this task over to them. These are the kind of problems they eat for breakfast.

Best of luck.